# Show off your hats!

Tags: discussion

It is [Winter Bash](http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com) on the Salesforce Stack Exchange.  Show off your favorite hat(s) here.

Answer (score 7):

[image: Peter Knolle with USA Hat]

> What!!!??? You're telling me the code has SOQL inside of a for loop???

Comment: No, he said he didn't understand why his trigger on `Accounts` didn't fired when he updated a related `contact` to `Accounts`, you know, the one that's a child of a 3rd cousin! It was clear to him, just because he didn't include any code in the question doesn't mean it shouldn't have been clear to you too! You **are** psychoctic aren't you??

Answer (score 5):

Chameleon...It goes well with my Picture...:)

[image]

Comment: so cute hat :)))

Answer (score 3):

I've got three already and am not always certain which one to wear for the occasion. One was even a "hidden hat" not on the list. ;P

Comment: I've gotten *only* hidden hats so far.

Comment: Cool! Must mean more bounty to be found. :)

Comment: Too bad Meta apparently isn't included. I got my 100 day gold star here yesterday and didn't get a hat for it. Had it been in SF.SE, I'd have gotten another hat. I like the new one I got this morning though.

Answer (score 3):

Mine actually fits pretty well.

Answer (score 2):

Here I go! with a hat from where I am from - Indian origin - hairy @#$@#$!

Answer (score 2):

[image]

> Hey recruit! Is it a harrrrdcoded ID in your code?!

Answer (score 2):

I got the selfie hat!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

ATM am with five, but two are said to be secret hats. God knows what are those. Oh no I should know what hat is on my head...!

UPDATE: found which are my secret hats from [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245170/winter-bash-2014-secret-hats) @crmprogdev check for yours'

Answer (score 1):

q=) q=) q=) q=) q=) q=) q=) q=)

Answer (score 1):

It goes well with my skin tone ;)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have got 6 and i preferred coolest one

[image]